# Adding a date historylist for deposit and withdraw in bankaccount java

Tags: java, class, date, arraylist

I've been banging my head for a while now with this problem. I want to add a historylist of withdrawals and deposits to my bankaccount program. I made a subclass, Transaction to my superklass, Account with these methods:

```
import java.util.*;


public class Transaction extends Account{
private double amount;

public String addDeposit() {
    Account newDep = new Account();
    Date date = new Date();
    newDep.deposit(amount); 
    return date + "\tIN: " + amount + "\t" + getBalance();  
}

public String addWithdraw() {
    Account newWith = new Account();
    Date date = new Date();
    newWith.withdraw(amount);   
    return date + "\tUT: " + amount + "\t" + getBalance();  
}

public String getTransactionHistory()
{
    return;
}
}
```

I would like to add an if-statement that prints out if its a withdrawal or deposit. But how do I do that? I'm not even sure this is the easiest way to go to put the transaction in another subclass.

Comment: To me, it doesn't seem right to have `Transaction extends Account`, because this means that a `Transaction` is a type of `Account`, that is, all `Transaction`s are also `Account`s.  This doesn't fit my real life understanding of what transactions and accounts are.

Comment: @DavidWallace Ok, I make it a class of it's own. Do you have any suggestion of how to make it work? How to get the withdrawals and deposits with transactionday...

Comment: It seems to me that you'd want to have a `List<Transaction>` as a field of the `Account` class.  An account **has a** list of transactions.  Then, every time you transact, you add something to the list.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes, that's exactly how I want it. I have an ArrayList, Transaction in Account, but I don't know how to get the deposit and withdraw together with date in that list...

Comment: Well, I think your `Transaction` class needs to have an amount and a date as fields.  Maybe an additional field to indicate whether it's a deposit or a withdrawal (although there are other ways to deal with this issue, for example, you could always have a negative amount for a withdrawal).  Then, every time you process a deposit or a withdrawal on the `Account`, you can create one of these objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Represent such information as instances of classes, not as strings.

As the comments discussed, you need a different class design. You should have an *Account* class that represents the bank account, with members (fields) for date-time opened, date-time closed, a collection of co-owners (must have at least one), and so on. Each transaction is recorded in a separate class, *Transaction*. Transaction does *not* extend from account. Rather, an Account contains a collection of Transaction instances. The Transaction class would have members such as date-time when transacted, what person was the customer (a co-owner or possibly someone else or some legal entity), what staff person executed the transaction, the amount of money, and whether it was a deposit or withdrawal.

Big tip: The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. They have been supplanted in Java 8 by the new java.time package. Or use the Joda-Time library. Learn to specify a time zone, using UTC in your database and in most of your programming. Adjust to a time zone only for presentation in the UI and where your business logic demands it.